# Is anyone using or working on the Skeleton Framework?

Tags: skeleton-css-boilerplate

I'm wondering if anyone is working on or using the Skeleton Framework (http://www.getskeleton.com) any more? The GitHub site does show a little activity from time to time but I'm wondering if there is a way for me to chat with people that know what's going on with it.

I've been using the framework at work one all of my recent projects and I want to get a little more involved with it's development.

Thanks

Comment: @GovindSingh I didn't state I want to begin a chat session on Stackoverflow. Please read the **entire** post.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about contributing to third party software

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently using it to build my portfolio site. Haven't seen any recent changes to it but it does seem to be getting used quite a bit from what I've researched. I enjoy how it's bare bones, simple to use and ready to go with your own custom code. You have something you need help with?